# Multi model explanation for Audio Visual speech enhancement (AVSE)

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I was trying to understand how does multi model work for Audio visual speech enhancement. As far i understood that Audio features (spectogram) and Visual features (lip region) is fed to CNN seperately and then combined together to same Linear layer or same CNN. But my main question is how is It even combined and how does network even work as Spectogram and Lip are 2 very different features. And lator on how does network out put only the desired output as 2 features were combined into one. Please give any explanation which would increase my understanding. Also sharing study materials would be helpfull.

I read the following papers and github.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.11769.pdf

https://r.search.yahoo.com/_ylt=Awr1VTQA.8Rk8LsoVpS7HAx.;_ylu=Y29sbwNzZzMEcG9zAzEEdnRpZAMEc2VjA3Ny/RV=2/RE=1690659713/RO=10/RU=https%3a%2f%2fgithub.com%2fSindhu-Hegde%2fpseudo-visual-speech-denoising/RK=2/RS=ITcSuqQh5ri9y35ZnJ0.6YrDDgA-

https://github.com/cogmhear/Intelligibility-Oriented-Audio-Visual-Speech-Enhancement